# Why is my define call not triggering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd, requirejs-define

I'm using `requireJS` and am trying to define a Google maps module.

I'm adding this code to the end of HTML snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready");
  define(['async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false'],
   function (gmap) {
     console.log(gmap);
   });
});
```

The "ready" console is logging but the `define` call is not triggering. If I replace it with a `require` call, the file is being loaded, but I gmap is undefined.

**Question:**
why is my `define` call not triggering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because once a module is defined it needs to be required. Changing your code to something like this would work:

```
// gmap.js (for example)
define(['async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false'], function(gmap) {
    // Do some stuff

    return gmap;
});

// main.js
require(['jquery', 'path/to/gmap'], function($, gmap) {
    $(function() {
        console.log(gmap);
    });
});
```

Some things to note:

- Modules that are defined should live in individual files. Read [this page in the API documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define) to grasp how they work.
- Avoid requiring modules inside a DOM ready callback, this means you have to wait longer before the modules can be requested. Better to start requesting them straight away and check for DOM readiness later. RequireJS comes with [a DOM ready plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#domReady) just for this.
- Ensure you `require` jQuery as a module (unless you aren't using it as such).
- Passing an anonymous function to `$()` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was a little reluctant to declare my module in "the middle of nowhere" so thanks for reconfirming. I got it to work using only a require call, but since I need the functionality on multiple pages, I wanted to register gmap as a module. Anyway. works now as module, so thanks for helping out!